error Option Strict On disallows operands of type Object for operator '=' in datagridview with vb.net
I have an error Error  BC32013 Option Strict On disallows operands of type Object for operator '='. Use the 'Is' operator to test for object identity.in datagridview with vb.net
The purpose of the code is Check cell is empty or has value 0 or If it is empty and has a value of 0, then addnew rows are not allowed
Please guide me so that I can solve the error
Thanks
 
   Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
        If keyData = Keys.Tab AndAlso CBool(Keys.Enter) Then
            Dim SelectDgv = GetSELECT()
            If Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
 'error below line code
    If Not DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).Any(Function(cell) String.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.FormattedValue?.ToString()) OrElse cell.FormattedValue = 0) Then
                    BindingSource1.AddNew()
                Else
                    DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1)
                    DataGridView1.BeginEdit(False)

                End If
            Else
            End If
            Return True
        ElseIf keyData = Keys.F1 AndAlso CBool(Keys.Enter) Then
            DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(5)
            DataGridView1.BeginEdit(False)
        Else
        End If
        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
    End Function



You cannot have this: cell.FormattedValue = 0. Cast to string beforehand, then compare the result with string.Empty and/or "0" (simplified)

@Jimi , thanks for reply , If Not DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).Any(Function(cell) String.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.FormattedValue?.ToString()) OrElse cell.FormattedValue = 0) Then How I changed this line code with your recommendation? Please guide me

The FormattedValue can never be a number. It's formatted, so it must be a String at least. For some reason though, Microsoft chose to declare that property as type Object, so cast it as type String and then compare it to a String. You should not need to ask us how to do either of those very basic things.
